# Delete from entity in D365 F&O OData using postman HTTP Request

Tags: http-headers, microsoft-dynamics

I have this Dynamics entity URL:

```
https://****.dynamics.com/data/PAWorkerSignDetails(5637144576)
```

I can create or show all workers and its fields, but I can't delete or update it. I get this message:

> No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI '***.dynamics.com/data/PAWorkerSignDetails(RecIdPrimary=5637144576)'.
> No route data was found for this request.

And I am sure about this link - and `5637144576` is the primary key in entity table.

I tried to use to `(RecIdPrimary=5637144576)` instead of value only but I get the same message.

Comment: With "type" of Dynamics are you talking about? The one I know (CE = Customer Engagement - or Sales) typically uses **GUID**s as the entity ID - not numbers.

Comment: Dynamics  finance and operation